# Azure ASE v2 - restrict network access for app services

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway, azure-ase

I have an ILB ASE v2 with WAF (public IP). The ASE has its subnet where all web apps reside. For obvious security reasons I think I need to lock down access from Internet and leave only HTTPS open. But when I do that I can't see app services info in the portal. So what should my NSG look like for this subnet?

Also, WAF has its own subnet. It doesn't have NSG assigned either. Should it have one?

Comment: What's the specific error message? Do you follow [this blog](https://sabbour.me/how-to-run-an-app-service-behind-a-waf-enabled-application-gateway/) to setup ILB ASE+WAF? You want to`leave only HTTPS open.`, How do you configure this for HTTPS? It's an HTTPS listener?

Comment: No message, the portal just can't load anything related to those app services.

No, I follow official docs. Let me try something unofficial now...

yes, the listener is HTTPS only. So are app services.

Comment: ok, I read that blog post. It's for newbies. not relevant to my question

Comment: The app GW subnet and ASE subnet should be in the same VNet. Any error message when you access the web app via app GW? What's the backend health in the app GW portal? Check if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-gateway-internal-load-balancer-app-service-environment) helps?

Comment: they are in the same subnet obviously. I'm trying to restrict access by using NSG. so I thought I'd add NSG to ASE subnet. but adding it blocks the portal from getting information about apps. and my question is HOW would you restrict access to the apps that are inside ASE (like HTTPS only)

Comment: If you want to restrict the app with HTTPS in ASE, you could add the rules like this: `rule name: inbound-https 443 source (ASE subnet address range); rule name outbound-443 443 destination (ASE subnet address range)` in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#network-security-groups

Comment: please read my question again. this is exactly what I did!

Comment: `but adding it blocks the portal from getting information about apps`, if you means kudu site, you can directly access it via kudu site URL instead of from the portal, any other specific worries? Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#portal-dependencies

Comment: NO, not kudu! look, let someone else who actually knows this stuff answer the question.

Comment: alvipeo, can you please reach out to us at azcommunity@microsoft.com with your subscription ID and the URL of this post? We would like to work closer with you on this matter.

Comment: sent yesterday.

Comment: sent just now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the resulting rules set for ASE subnet NSG:

[image]

you might want to add HTTP to it if you need it.

Comment: Awesome. If my suggestion helped you, please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

When you add a NSG to the AppSercice subnet with Deny All internet traffic, it is blocking the portal to fetch information from App Device. Try adding a NSG rule with greater priority with source IP as Azure Cloud tag and allow it.

So you are blocking all Internet traffic and allowing Azure IPs for communication.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes, I made it work. but I had to add multiple rules